# requests.get is not fetching all tags. i need table for that page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

`requests.get` is not fetching all tags. i need table for [that page](https://www.covid19india.org/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source=requests.get("https://www.covid19india.org/").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"html.parser")
```

Comment: page is dynamic. you can get that data through the api

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to pull that table as it is dynamically rendered and is not present in a simple request html. The data does come from an api which you can go directly to. Then take that json response to construct a table.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

jsonData = requests.get('https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json').json()

rows = []
results = pd.DataFrame()
for state, v1 in jsonData.items():
    for district, v2 in v1['districtData'].items():
        active = v2['active']
        confirmed = v2['confirmed']
        deceased = v2['deceased']
        recovered = v2['recovered']
        
        rows.append([state, district, active, confirmed, deceased, recovered])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['State','District','Active','Confirmed','Deceased','Recovered'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                           State                  District  ...  Deceased  Recovered
0               State Unassigned                Unassigned  ...         0          0
1    Andaman and Nicobar Islands                  Nicobars  ...         0          0
2    Andaman and Nicobar Islands  North and Middle Andaman  ...         0          1
3    Andaman and Nicobar Islands             South Andaman  ...         0         32
4                 Andhra Pradesh                 Anantapur  ...         4         92
5                 Andhra Pradesh                  Chittoor  ...         1         97
6                 Andhra Pradesh             East Godavari  ...         0         43
7                 Andhra Pradesh                    Guntur  ...         8        328
8                 Andhra Pradesh                   Krishna  ...        15        280
9                 Andhra Pradesh                   Kurnool  ...        21        447
10                Andhra Pradesh               Other State  ...         0         25
11                Andhra Pradesh                  Prakasam  ...         0         63
12                Andhra Pradesh            S.P.S. Nellore  ...         4        103
13                Andhra Pradesh                Srikakulam  ...         0          5
14                Andhra Pradesh             Visakhapatnam  ...         1         47
15                Andhra Pradesh              Vizianagaram  ...         0          4
16                Andhra Pradesh             West Godavari  ...         0         54
17                Andhra Pradesh             Y.S.R. Kadapa  ...         0         76
18                Andhra Pradesh                   Unknown  ...         1         67
19             Arunachal Pradesh                     Anjaw  ...         0          0
20             Arunachal Pradesh                 Changlang  ...         0          0
21             Arunachal Pradesh               East Kameng  ...         0          0
22             Arunachal Pradesh                East Siang  ...         0          0
23             Arunachal Pradesh                     Kamle  ...         0          0
24             Arunachal Pradesh                 Kra Daadi  ...         0          0
25             Arunachal Pradesh              Kurung Kumey  ...         0          0
26             Arunachal Pradesh                 Lepa Rada  ...         0          0
27             Arunachal Pradesh                     Lohit  ...         0          1
28             Arunachal Pradesh                  Longding  ...         0          0
29             Arunachal Pradesh       Lower Dibang Valley  ...         0          0
..                           ...                       ...  ...       ...        ...
733                  Uttarakhand               Rudraprayag  ...         0          0
734                  Uttarakhand             Tehri Garhwal  ...         0          0
735                  Uttarakhand         Udham Singh Nagar  ...         0          5
736                  Uttarakhand                Uttarkashi  ...         0          0
737                  Uttarakhand                   Unknown  ...         0          2
738                  West Bengal                Alipurduar  ...         0          0
739                  West Bengal                   Bankura  ...         0          0
740                  West Bengal                   Birbhum  ...         0          6
741                  West Bengal               Cooch Behar  ...         0          0
742                  West Bengal          Dakshin Dinajpur  ...         0          0
743                  West Bengal                Darjeeling  ...         1          5
744                  West Bengal                   Hooghly  ...         6        109
745                  West Bengal                    Howrah  ...        34        200
746                  West Bengal                Jalpaiguri  ...         0          4
747                  West Bengal                  Jhargram  ...         0          0
748                  West Bengal                 Kalimpong  ...         1          6
749                  West Bengal                   Kolkata  ...       172        568
750                  West Bengal                     Malda  ...         0         10
751                  West Bengal               Murshidabad  ...         1          4
752                  West Bengal                     Nadia  ...         0          9
753                  West Bengal         North 24 Parganas  ...        35        156
754                  West Bengal               Other State  ...         1          5
755                  West Bengal         Paschim Bardhaman  ...         2         10
756                  West Bengal         Paschim Medinipur  ...         0         19
757                  West Bengal           Purba Bardhaman  ...         0          5
758                  West Bengal           Purba Medinipur  ...         1         31
759                  West Bengal                   Purulia  ...         0          0
760                  West Bengal         South 24 Parganas  ...         5         46
761                  West Bengal            Uttar Dinajpur  ...         0          0
762                  West Bengal                   Unknown  ...         0          0

[763 rows x 6 columns]
```